# Magento Checkout

Tags: magento

Hi I want to retrieve the attributes of the first checkout product, so that when the user selects any of the products with similar attributes all the options should be pre-selected (the drop downs)

Ex. if a user buys a tee shirt with attribute size 'M'.

Next time when he browses through the catalog and selects any other tee shirt, its size should be auto selected to 'M'

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To identify user after browser close you have 2 possibilities:

A: via customer login. Meaning customer logs in->product page is loaded->your module select custom option.
B: via cookies. You custom module sets and gets cookies.

The problems are:

1. You might not have customer login at all.
2. Customer might not login before checkout.
3. Cookies might be cleaned after browser close.
4. Customer might not want to buy the same size clothes.

Options are echoed in this layout xml:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
```

So you can change this and implement your custom logic with your custom module.

**UPDATE 1**

You can use Mage::getSingleton('core/session',array('name'=>'frontend')) or mage::registry

Comment: This is not wot i am looking for... I want to get the attributes for the particular session only, not after the browser is closed

Comment: use Mage::registry and core session